# How do I write a simulation in r for a "gambling" problem and return probability?

Tags: r, function, simulation

I am attempting to run a simulation in R and I'm not really sure where to start. The problem is as follows:

"You have $100 and are making $10 bets on a fair game. What is the probability that you will have lost all your money by the time you have placed your 100th bet?"

So far I've written a small function to generate random results from a "coin flip" but that's as far as I've gotten.

```
win.lose <- function(x){
  sample(0:1, x, rep=TRUE)
}
```

My concern is that this function doesn't consider making money from winnings. Some help here writing a better function for the problem above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[r](/questions/tagged/r) works best using vectorization. Instead of a loop, we should sample all at once:

```
sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
```

We also know that if we net 10 losses, we would be broke. The translates to a cumulative sum:

```
cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE))

any(cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)) == -10)
```

Finally, we can use `replicate()` to repeat this exact same simulation:

```
#specify simulation criteria
n <- 100 
n_sim <- 10

# betting criteria
n_broke <- 10 #if we have 10 net losses, we're broke
bet <- 10 #each bet is $10

# way 1
set.seed(123)
replicate(n_sim, cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE))) 

#or with actual money totals - note, 1st row is the initial money amount
set.seed(123)
replicate(n_sim, cumsum(c(n_broke * bet, bet * sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE))))

#or a summary of it:
set.seed(123)
table(replicate(n_sim, ifelse(any(cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE)) == -n_broke), 'Out_of_Money', 'Has_Money')))

#faster way to do it:
set.seed(123)
table(
  ifelse(
    apply(matrix(sample(c(-1,1), n * n_sim, replace = TRUE), ncol = n_sim),
          2,
          function(x) min(cumsum(x)) <= -n_broke),
    'Out_of_Money', 'Has_Money')
)
```

For n_sim = 10,000:

```
   Has_Money Out_of_Money 
        6783         3217
```

And what's happening behind the scenes:

```
set.seed(123)
replicate(n_sim, cumsum(c(n_broke * bet, bet * sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE))))
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100
  [2,]   90   90  110  110   90  110  110  110   90   110
  [3,]   80  100  120  120   80  120  120  100   80   120
  [4,]   70  110  130  110   70  130  130   90   90   110
  [5,]   80  100  120  120   60  140  120   80  100   100
  [6,]   70  110  130  110   50  130  110   90   90   110
  [7,]   80  120  140  100   40  120  100   80   80   120
  [8,]   90  110  150  110   50  110   90   70   70   130
  [9,]  100  100  140  100   40  100  100   60   60   120
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple problem with the `binomial` distribution.

- **First**: since we are interested to calculate the probability '*by the time you have placed your 100th bet*', we need to calculate maximum how many successes we can make before the 100th trial in order to run out of money:
  The equation that needs to be solved is: `100 + 20*X + (99 - X)*(-10) <= 0`, where `X` is the necessary number of *successes* that should be made among 99 trials. This leads to `36` successes only.
- **Second**: since we already know that we need `36` successes out of `99` bets, we can use `pbinom` function to calculate the probability of getting `36` or less *successes* if we gambled 99 times:

  `pbinom(36,99,0.5)`

which lead to probability of `0.004316793`.

This is a generic framework for a fair game that can be used with any amount of initial wealth, betting money and termination trial.

**NB:** By the way, this calculates the exact probability in comparison to any simulation method!

Comment: But the simulations are so much more fun! +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simulation of 100 bets like so.

```
library(dplyr)

current_balance <- 100
bet <- 10
odds <- 0.5

for(i in 1:100) {

  current_balance <- current_balance - bet # place bet

  outcome <- ifelse(runif(1) > 0.5, 
                    bet * 2, # win: receive twice the bet ($20)
                    0) # lose and the initial $10 is lost

  current_balance <- current_balance + outcome

  paste("Balance after", i, "bets is:", current_balance) %>% print

  if(current_balance <= 0) { stop() }
}
```

You could wrap the whole thing in another loop to run the simulation more than one time, and record the results, like so

```
ending_balances <- c()

for(s in 1:10) {

current_balance <- 100
bet <- 10
odds <- 0.5

  for(i in 1:100) {

    current_balance <- current_balance - bet # place bet

    outcome <- ifelse(runif(1) > 0.5, 
                      bet * 2, # win: receive twice the bet ($20)
                      0) # lose and the initial $10 is lost

    current_balance <- current_balance + outcome

    # paste("Balance after", i, "bets is:", current_balance) %>% print

    if(current_balance <= 0) { 

      ending_balances[s] <- current_balance
      break() 
      }

    ending_balances[s] <- current_balance

  }

}



> ending_balances
 [1]   0  80 220  60   0 120   0  80   0 200
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function to `sample` -10 (lost) and 20 (won) 100 times and return `TRUE` if anytime in 100 bets we lose all our money (100 $).

```
lost.balance <- function() {
  total <- cumsum(sample(c(-10, 20), 100, replace = TRUE))
  any(total <= -100)
}
```

We can simulate using `replicate` `n` times and calculate the ratio using `table`

```
n <- 10000
table(replicate(n, lost.balance()))/n

#   FALSE   TRUE 
#  0.9902 0.0098
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 100, you use 10, then you only have 90. The trick here is what is your gain if you win. If double, you need to `sample(c(-1,2), 100, rep=TRUE)`.

```
win.lose <- function(){
    total <- 90
        for(i in c(1:100)){
                bet_output <- sample(c(-1,2), 1, rep=TRUE)
                total <- total + 10 * bet_output
                if(total<0) return(total)
        }
        return(total)
}

sim_y <- unlist(lapply(c(1:10000), function(i){win.lose()} ))
sum(sim_y < 0)/length(sim_y)
```